# What happens if a clock source is connected to a CMOS inverter and the clock changes its value faster than the delay of the inverter?

Tags: mosfet, cmos

Suppose that a clock source of periodic time equals 10 ns (i.e. its value changes every 5 ns). That source is connected to a CMOS inverter whose propagation delay is 8 ns. Now if the clock is high, the inverter should output low signal after 8 ns but at that time the clock value will be changed to become low. What is the behavior of the inverter in this case?

Comment: Is this concerning any particular logic family, or is it about the methods of timing analysis?

Comment: This sounds it is a copy-paste from homework/exam question without even a guess.

Comment: @Justme , No it is not, It is actually a simplified version of another more complex question and it is useful in understanding glitch power in CMOS circuits. Take more time to consider the question because it is not as naiive as you think.

Comment: @screamer OK, but if you want to know what happens in practice, you should determine what kind of real world clock signal is really being fed into what kind of real world inverter. Square waves are ideal signals that don't exist in real life. In real life, they have rise and fall times too, and maybe the answer could be just looked up from inverter data sheet.

Comment: @Justme , I didn't state that I want to know what happens in practice, I wanted to know the behavior of the inverter even in simulation. So, if you are not willing to help then leave the question and don't just spam without any reason.

Comment: @screamer But you never mentioned you are simulating this in a simulator. To get an answer, what simulator you are using, and what kind of inverter it simulates? What happens in the simulator, depends on the simulator and how it models the simulated components. I mean, how can we answer what will happen, if we have no clue about your environment. Besides, if you have a simulator, why ask here, instead of just doing the simulation, because then we don't have to guess the simulator output.

Comment: This is going to depend on the model your simulator uses.

Comment: @Justme , Just don't spam. I didn't ask for an answer from you specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Not easy to predict. Perhaps it will be a delayed version of the input, or perhaps it won't. I've used this sort of thing as a "poor man's" time to amplitude converter, where the amplitude of the output pulse measured the input pulse width.